# Counting lattice points with relatively prime coordinates

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

**My Question:** Here is a fact, and a proof of said fact. I am wondering if someone can provide a cleaner/less convoluted argument, as it seems to me like a fact that ought to possess a very simple proof. Actually, it would be nice to see any substantially different proof.

> **Fact:** Consider the sets of lattice points $$R = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{N}^{2}
> \, : \, 1\le x, y \le n \, , \gcd(x,y) = 1, \text{ and } x+y\leq n\}$$
>   $$S = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{N}^{2} \, : \, 1\le x, y \le n \, ,
> \gcd(x,y) = 1, \text{ and } x+y > n\}$$ Then, we have $|S| = |R| + 1$.

*Proof:* For each $k \in \mathbb{N}$, we have the sets $$S_{k} = \left\{(x,y) \in S \, : \, k \le \frac{x}{y} < k+1\right\}$$ $$R_{k, <} = \left\{(x,y) \in R \, : \, k\le \frac{n-x}{y} < k+1 \, ,\,  x<y\right\}$$

We have a map $f_k : S_k  \to R_{k,<}$ sending $(x,y) \mapsto (x-ky, y)$, which is in fact a bijection for $k\neq n$, with inverse $(x,y) \mapsto (x+ky, y)$. When $k = n$, it is almost a bijection, i.e. $f_n$ is a bijection from $S_n \setminus \{(n,1)\}$ onto $R_{n, <}$.

Since we have disjoint unions $$\bigcup_{k\ge 1} R_{k,<} = R \cap \{x<y\}$$  $$\bigcup_{k\ge 1} S_k = S \cap \{x\ge y\}$$ it follows that $|R \cap \{x<y\}| = |S \cap \{x\ge y\}| - 1$. Noting that $|R \cap \{x<y\}| = |R \cap \{x>y\}|$ via the map $(x,y) \mapsto (y,x)$, and similarly $|S \cap \{x\ge y\}| = |S \cap \{x < y\}|$, it follows that (taking care not to forget $(1,1) \in R$) we have $$|R| = 1+ 2|R \cap \{x<y\}| = 1+2(|S\cap \{x\ge y\}| - 1) = |S| - 1$$ as desired. $\blacksquare$

Answer (score 1):

A heuristic start:

Note, that you form a diagonal line with the equals of the first set. This line has $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ points, on or below it. The total lattice has $n^2$ so in theory $n^2-n(n-1)=1$ but that's false (it's actually n). What we failed to consider, is coprimality that will decrease the numbers.